# Linear programing modeling

Tags: linear-programming

I am trying to prepare for my Linear programing exam and i stumbled upon an exercice that i can't wrap my head around. It goes like this.

**Seven** days before the final match a tennis player is trying to optimize his training sessions. He has 4 different training options - **Serving**, **Volley**, **Right-hand hits**, **Back-hand hits**. He predicted the number of points he could obtain based on the repartition of the training sessions.

|  | Right-Hand | Back-Hand | Volley | Service |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 7 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 | 7 | 6 | 7 |

The columns represent the different types of training and the lines represent the number of days dedicated. The intersection is the estimated points he would obtain during the final match. For example if he chose to do 4 days of Right-Hand training he would obtain 5 points in the final match. The goal is to maximize the amount of points he would get.

**Note:** The player must dedicate at least 1 day for each training type.

**Solution:**

We can put x1 = days of Right-hand training, x2 = back-hand etc...
In total he has 7 days so the first constraint would be:

x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 <= 7

He has to dedicate 1 day to each training type so x1, x2, x3, x4 >= 1 and x1, x2, x3, x4 are integer values. The problem i have is i don't know how to correlate these values to the numbers of points since the maximization requires to find the biggest number of points obtainable.

Comment: Must the player train everyday?

Comment: There is nothing specified about him taking any breaks so in order to maximize the amount of points obtained i would assume that he'd have to train everyday.

Comment: I don't know if this is true for your specific values, but this is certainly false in general. Consider for example the case in which the amount of points for each training type is decreasing w.r.t. the number of days spent with that training type (even in your instance these points are sometime decreasing).

Comment: I see so basically if i were to take 2 random examples where he does 1 day of each training putting him at 16 points vs where he does 1 of each but 2 of service is putting him at 14 points. Despite training for more days he ends up with less points in the end. Is this what you're hinting at?

Comment: Yes.$\vphantom{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $i \in \{2,3,4\}$ and $j \in \{1,2,3,4\}$,let $x_{i,j}$ be an indicator variable that is $1$ if and only if at least $i$ days are spent doing the  $j$-th type of training.

Let $c_{i,j}$ be the number of points gained if exactly $i$ days are spent doing the $j$-th type of training.

What you want to optimize is described the following integer linear program, assuming that it is not necessary to train every day.

$$
\max \sum_{j=1}^4 \sum_{i=2}^4 x_{i,j} \left( c_i - c_{i-1}  \right) + \sum_{j=1}^4 c_{1,j} \quad \mbox{s.t.} \\
\sum_{j=1}^4 \sum_{i=2}^4 x_{i,j} \le 3 \\
x_{i+1,j} \le x_{i,j}  \quad \forall  i \in \{2,3\}, \forall j \in \{1,2,3,4\} \\
x_{i,j} \in \{0,1\} \quad \forall i \in \{2,3,4\}, \forall j \in \{1,2,3,4\}
$$

If it is necessary to train every day, then the first constraint becomes $\sum_{j=1}^4 \sum_{i=2}^4 x_{i,j} = 3$.